# Vectoring the FOR loop while computing rows of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Following is the sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': pd.date_range(start='2023-03-15 00:00:00', periods=15, freq='1min'),
    'binary': [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    'nonbinary': np.random.randint(1, 10, 15)
})
```

My task is:

To find the presence of `1s` in column 'binary' (either a single occurrence or in a consecutive manner) and change the rows (that have `0s`) that are two minutes back (previous) with `1s`. For example, the resultant 'binary' column should be:

```
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0] --> Original

  [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0] --> New
```

My following snippet works fine and gives the expected result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': pd.date_range(start='2023-03-15 00:00:00', periods=15, freq='1min'),
    'binary': [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    'nonbinary': np.random.randint(1, 10, 15)
})

# create a copy of the binary column to store the updated values
updated_binary = df['binary'].copy()

# iterate through the rows of the DataFrame
for i in range(len(df)):

    # check if the current row has a binary value of 1
    if df.loc[i, 'binary'] == 1:

        # update the corresponding rows in binary to 1
        updated_binary[max(0, i-2):i+1] = 1

# update the binary column with the updated values
df['binary'] = updated_binary

# print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

The problem is, my actual `dataframe` consists of thousands of rows. I want to make my computation faster by using [vectorization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vectorization-in-python/). Following is my attempt to solve it using vectorization:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': pd.date_range(start='2023-03-15 00:00:00', periods=15, freq='1min'),
    'binary': [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    'nonbinary': np.random.randint(1, 10, 15)
})

# create a copy of the binary column to store the updated values
updated_binary = df['binary'].copy()

# create a boolean array to identify the positions of 1s in binary column
Ones_positions = df['binary'].eq(1).values

# create a sliding window of size 3 to find the positions of 0s two minutes before the 1s
window = np.zeros(3, dtype=bool)
window[:2] = True

zero_positions = np.logical_and.reduce((
    np.roll(Ones_positions, 2), 
    np.logical_not(Ones_positions),
    np.convolve(window, np.ones(3, dtype=bool), mode='valid') == 2
), axis=0)

# update the corresponding positions in the updated_binary to 1
updated_binary[zero_positions] = 1

# update the binary column with the updated values
df['binary'] = updated_binary

# print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

But I get the following error:

```
zero_positions = np.logical_and.reduce((
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Given your example, it looks like you meant `2min`, not `2s` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reversed [`rolling.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.max.html), with 2+1 minutes as period:

```
N = 2
df['new'] = (df[::-1].rolling(f'{N+1}min', on='time',
                              min_periods=1)
             ['binary'].max()
            )
```

*NB. we need to add +1 to account for the current row.*

Output:

```
                  time  binary  nonbinary  new
0  2023-03-15 00:00:00       0          2  0.0
1  2023-03-15 00:01:00       0          2  0.0
2  2023-03-15 00:02:00       0          5  1.0
3  2023-03-15 00:03:00       0          7  1.0
4  2023-03-15 00:04:00       1          4  1.0
5  2023-03-15 00:05:00       0          6  0.0
6  2023-03-15 00:06:00       0          9  0.0
7  2023-03-15 00:07:00       0          8  1.0
8  2023-03-15 00:08:00       0          4  1.0
9  2023-03-15 00:09:00       1          3  1.0
10 2023-03-15 00:10:00       1          1  1.0
11 2023-03-15 00:11:00       1          4  1.0
12 2023-03-15 00:12:00       1          1  1.0
13 2023-03-15 00:13:00       1          5  1.0
14 2023-03-15 00:14:00       0          5  0.0
```

Comment: It would seem that given there is one row per minute, you could just use `df['new'] = df['binary'][::-1].rolling(3, min_periods=1).max()`

Comment: @mozway
Your code works but the 'time' column is also edited. I want the 'time' column to be unchanged. Every row of 'time' should be the same. Only rows of 'binary' are allowed to be changed.

Comment: @santobedi it shouldn't affect the "time" column, please double check. Note that if you're looking at the intermediate output before assignment, it's in reverse order, but this will come back in the original order after assignment.

Comment: @Nick yes that's true, but using an explicit `'3min'` would work in any case ;)

Comment: @mozway The 'time' column is fine. My real data has `10s` interval.  I replaced `min` with `S` and it worked. But it works only when `N>815`. Any value of `N` less than `815` shows no effect (i.e., 'binary' and 'new' columns are the same for `N<815`). The `new`  column should be different than the  `binary` column when  `N>10`.

Comment: @Nick 's solution worked. :)